# Check Blocked input by Telerik

Tags: telerik

On the page there is a checkBox and input. When this checkBox is non-allocated input is blocked.

For UI-testing using Telerik Framework + NUnit.

Tell me, please, how to check if a field is locked?

P.S. Translated by Google Translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

To check to:

```
Assert.IsFalse ([interesting_input].IsEnabled);
```